# How to change secondary parent relationship line to be same as other linkType styles?

Tags: getorgchart

I'm evaluating GetOrgChart for a project which requires some nodes to use the second parent relationship feature. The default line style/path for these second parent relationships it a direct line to the parent node.

Is there a way to change this line style so it matches the "M" or "B" link type styles and goes around other nodes?

[second parent link style example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKGKL.png)